# No Content available inside text file Google Drive API v3 Java

Tags: java, google-drive-realtime-api

I have uploaded a simple plain text file, But when I check the text file in Google drive it shows no content inside uploaded text file.
Below is my approach:-

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
fileMetadata.setName("135.txt");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("text/plain");

    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(createdFolderId));
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("C:\\textFile.txt");

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", filePath);
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = null;
try
    {
        file = service.files().create(fileMetadata).setFields("id,parents").execute();
    }catch(
    IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Try to use the [sample code given in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#basic_uploads). Also, simple upload is the most applicable in your case as this is the most straightforward method for uploading file. Learn it [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload).

Comment: I have done that only. But when I go to google drive to read that file, All content inside that file is gone.